# Best way to make a dictionary out of one column?

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

I have an excel file that contains only 1 column, but all of the headers and values are in that same column.

As a practice Python project, I'm trying to use Openpyxl and Pandas to lay out the data how I want it.

i.e. It's a list of sports stats, that would be best displayed with the team names on the y-axis, and the stat categories in the x-axis.

However, the way the data is laid out in the column is:

- Stat Category Name (Goals as example)
- Team 1 Goals value
- Team 1 Name
- Team x Goals value
- Team x Name
- Stat Category 2 Name (Shots as example)
- Team 1 Stats value
- Team 1 Name

First, I created another column in excel that stores the character values of the column with the data in it.

Next, I created the variables 'statvalues' and 'charlength' that store the values of each column:

```
statvalues = sheet["A1:A266"]
charlength = sheet["B1:B266"]
```

Next, I created two empty lists, 'statvalueslist' and 'charlengthvaluelist', then appended the values in 'statvalues' and 'charlength' to their respective lists:

```
for row in statvalues:
    for cell in row:
        statcellvalue = cell.value
        statvalueslist.append(statcellvalue)

for row in charlength:
    for cell in row:
        charlengthvalue = cell.value
        charlengthvaluelist.append(charlengthvalue)
```

Then, I created a dictionary with the 'statcellvalue' as the key and 'charlengthvalue' as the value.

```
LiveStats_dict = dict(zip(statvalueslist, charlengthvaluelist))

for x in LiveStats_dict:
    print(x, LiveStats_dict[x])
```

This works, but gets rid of duplicates, and I'm really not sure where to go next.

What would be the best way to identify a key in a dictionary, then take the above key and change it to a value associated with that key? Or is there an easier way to get where I want?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you know the number of Teams or title of the stats?
Easiest method IMO would be read in pandas, convert to numpy and reshape.
Then you can "puncture" the teams name rows from the table to clean it out